# Ice cream shop offers 8 different flavours. How many different two-scoop dishes are possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

(Repetition is allowed) An Ice cream shop offers 8 different flavours of ice cream. How many different two-scoop dishes are possible if

(a) Two scoops are placed side by side in the dish?

(b) Two scoops are placed on top of the other?

Let the flavours be {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}.

My approach to the first question is using combination, since the order of the scoops doesn't matter.

C(8,2) = 28

And then, we combine the answer with 8 which represents the total number of repeated flavours {aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff,gg,hh}.
Therefore, the final answer is 28+8 = 36 ways.

For the second question, the order matters as the scoops are placed on top of the other. Therefore, it is permutation.

P(8,2) = 56

And then, similar to the first question, we combine the answer with 8 which represents the total number of repeated flavours. Therefore, the final answer is 56+8 = 64 ways.

However, I'm uncertain about my solutions and the approaches to solve the given problem. Therefore, I would like to request a comment upon my solution.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: This is all correct, though both answers could have been arrived at more directly.  The first by stars-and-bars as $\binom{2+8-1}{8-1}=\binom{9}{7}=36$ and the second as $8^2=64$.  The benefit of using these more direct approaches becomes clearer if we were getting three scoops or ten scoops or even more scoops of ice-cream at a time.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you so much for the clarification. It is my first time hearing about stars-and-bars and as you've mentioned, your method seems to be clearer. From now, I'm heading towards learning the stars-and-bars method.  Thank you once again for sharing the knowledge.